# ajaxcontroltoolkit htmleditor: both cleanup and keep the format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, html-editor

In an ajaxcontroltoolkit htmleditor, I would like to load an html formatted text from a file, keep its formatting, edit it and resave it.

While editing the text, if the user pastes in some text from ms word, I'd like to strip its formatting (but keep the formatting of the text in the htmleditor)

In my tries I either keep both formattings (formatting in editor an formatting from word), or loose both of them.

Is there a way to only strip the formatting from the pasted text?